# How can I split a T-SQL Command

Tags: t-sql, split, command-line-arguments, visual-foxpro

How can I split a T-SQL Command in

```
SELECT    FROM    WHERE    GROUP
```

For example i need split this command

```
Text To lcSQLCommand TextMerge NoShow Flags 1 Pretext 15
         SELECT a.HabitacionID, a.TipoID, b.AlquilerID, b.Desde, b.Hasta, IFNULL(b.Estado, 0) Estado,
                 c.Habitacion, c.Precio1 Precio
                 FROM habitaciones a
                      LEFT JOIN (SELECT HabitacionID, AlquilerID, Desde, Hasta, Estado
                                        FROM alquiler 
                                        WHERE (Estado = 2 AND Desde <= CURDATE()) OR Estado = 1
                                        ) b ON a.HabitacionID = b.HabitacionID
                      LEFT JOIN habitaciones_tipo c ON a.TipoID = c.TipoID
EndText
```

In

```
lcSQLSelect = "SELECT a.HabitacionID, a.TipoID, b.AlquilerID, b.Desde, b.Hasta, IFNULL(b.Estado, 0) Estado, c.Habitacion, c.Precio1 Precio"

lcSQLFrom = "FROM habitaciones a LEFT JOIN (SELECT HabitacionID, AlquilerID, Desde, Hasta, Estado FROM alquiler WHERE (Estado = 2 AND Desde <= CURDATE()) OR Estado = 1) b ON a.HabitacionID = b.HabitacionID LEFT JOIN habitaciones_tipo c ON a.TipoID = c.TipoID"

lcWhere = "" && No Where in this command

lcGroup = "" && No Group un this command
```

Best regards

Ze Roberto

> Text To lcSQLCommand TextMerge NoShow Flags 1 Pretext 15
>            SELECT a.HabitacionID, a.TipoID, b.AlquilerID, b.Desde, b.Hasta, IFNULL(b.Estado, 0) Estado,
>                    c.Habitacion, c.Precio1 Precio
>                    FROM habitaciones a
>                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT HabitacionID, AlquilerID, Desde, Hasta, Estado
>                                           FROM alquiler 
>                                           WHERE (Estado = 2 AND Desde <= CURDATE()) OR Estado = 1
>                                           ) b ON a.HabitacionID = b.HabitacionID
>                         LEFT JOIN habitaciones_tipo c ON a.TipoID = c.TipoID EndText

In

```
lcSQLSelect = "SELECT a.HabitacionID, a.TipoID, b.AlquilerID, b.Desde, b.Hasta, IFNULL(b.Estado, 0) Estado, c.Habitacion, c.Precio1 Precio"

lcSQLFrom = "FROM habitaciones a LEFT JOIN (SELECT HabitacionID, AlquilerID, Desde, Hasta, Estado FROM alquiler WHERE (Estado = 2 AND Desde <= CURDATE()) OR Estado = 1) b ON a.HabitacionID = b.HabitacionID LEFT JOIN habitaciones_tipo c ON a.TipoID = c.TipoID"

lcWhere = "" && No Where in this command

lcGroup = "" && No Group un this command
```

Comment: You could use a TSQL Parser to break the statement down into individual elements and then reassemble the various clauses as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the STREXTRACT() function. It lets you pull strings apart by specifying beginning and ending delimiters. So, for example, to get the field list, you'd use:

```
lcFieldList = STREXTRACT(lcSQLCommand, "SELECT", "FROM")
```

It gets trickier for the rest of what you need because you'll have to check for the presence of the WHERE and GROUP BY keywords to know exactly what delimiters you have, but the whole thing shouldn't be more than about 15 or 20 lines.

Note: I'm assuming you want to do this in VFP.

Comment: Maybe it can be a DLL library that allows me to use it in VFP

Comment: You should be able to do something similar in T-SQL. But why are you trying to split the query? What's the goal here?

Comment: I have a SQLTable object

<code>
Text To lcSQLCommand TextMerge NoShow Flags 1 Pretext 15
    SELECT a.HabitacionID, a.TipoID, b.AlquilerID, b.Desde, b.Hasta, IFNULL(b.Estado, 0) Estado,
....
EndText
loTable = NewObject("SQLTable", "MySQL.Vcx")
loTable.Open(lcSQLCommand, "habitaciones", "AlquilerID")

Internally separates the T-SQL command, for when I want to do a search, I only do this

loTable.Retrieve("b.AlquilerID = 5")

Thanks

Comment: @TamarE.Granor It gets more complicated when there are object names like `SelectionId` and `FromDate`.

Comment: @HABO Good point. Should probably include trailing blanks in the STREXTRACT() command for that.